# angular install cli errno -13

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

i am trying to install npm install -g @angular/cli
and i get this error

```
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/usr/local/lib/node_modules\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/admin/.npm/_logs/2019-08-04T05_20_10_235Z-debug.log
```

Tried following Commands repeatedly still did not worked.

1- i uninstall nodejs and reinstall old version

```
~ brew uninstall node 
~ which node
~ rm -rf /usr/local/bin/node
  ~cd /usr/local/lib
     ~ sudo rm -rf node
      ~ sudo rm -rf node_modules
```

2- clean cash

```
~ npm cache verify --force
~ npm cache clear --force 
~ npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
~ npm install -g @angular/cli
```

node version 
v8.16.0

npm version 
6.4.1

Answer (score 0):

Since the latest version of `Angular 8`, it requires `Node.js` version 10.9.0 or later.

Upgrade `Node.js` on your OS.

Check at documentation to setup your environment : https://angular.io/guide/setup-local

Answer (score 0):

From the error message it seems like a folder does not have write permission.

If you're on a windows machine, open a command prompt in "Run as Administrator" and execute the command.

If you're on a Mac, you'll have to give it permission using `chmod 777 /usr/local/lib/node_modules`

Answer (score 0):

On linux, I had to use sudo npm install...